# Cannot match values of type

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm just starting out with Swift 3 and I'm converting a Rails project to swift (side project while I learn)

Fairly simple, I have a Rails statement Im converting and Im getting many red errors in Xcode:

```
let startingPoint: Int = 1
let firstRange: ClosedRange = (2...10)
let secondRange: ClosedRange = (11...20)

func calc(range: Float) -> Float {
  switch range {
    case startingPoint:
     return (range - startingPoint) * 1 // or 0.2
    case firstRange:
     return // code
    default:
     return //code
  }
}
```

`calc` will either have an `Int` or `Float` value: `10` or `10.50`

Errors are:

> Expression pattern of type ClosedRange cannot match values of type Float
>
> Binary operator - cannot be applied to operands of type Float and Int

I understand the errors but I dont know what to search for to correct it. Could you point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Swift is strongly typed. Whenever you use a variable or pass something as a function argument, Swift checks that it is of the correct type. You can't pass a string to a function that expects an integer etc. Swift does this check at compile time (since it's statically typed).*

To adhere by that rules, try changing your code to this:

```
let startingPoint: Float = 1
let firstRange: ClosedRange<Float> = (2...10)
let secondRange: ClosedRange<Float> = (11...20)

func calc(range: Float) -> Float {
    switch range {
    case startingPoint:
        return (range - startingPoint) * 1 // or 0.2
    case firstRange:
    return 1.0 // 1.0 is just an example, but you have to return Float since that is defined in the method
    default:
        return 0.0 // 0.0 is just an example, put whatever you need here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi JPetric, Im getting `fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound` for `firstRange` is the `switch`

Comment: Never mind. I get errors because my ranges uses `let`. `var` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, you might want to specify ClosedRange to be of type Floats. Something similar to:

`let firstRange: ClosedRange<Float> = (2...10)`

For the second error, the problem is you are trying to compare a Float (range:Float) with an Int (startingPoint). So I would suggest you convert the startingPoint variable to a Float as well.